# How to customize Emacs keyboard shortcut for deleting current line

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization, text-editor, key-bindings

I want the current line to be deleted when <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and the letter <kbd>d</kbd> is pressed twice.

How can I achieve this inside my Emacs configuration file?

Currently all I have is this in my `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-9") 'prev-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-0") 'other-window)
```

Comment: Do you want to permanently disable the keyboard shortcut `Alt-d` aka `M-d` so that you can use two letter "d" instead?

Comment: If you wan't vim-like keyboard shortcut inside emacs, you can use evil: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil

Comment: I dont mind disabling it.   Because later I can use the same logic to bind Alt-dw to simulate M-d.    (dw meaning delete word, styled after vi editor)

Comment: i have tried evil before, it messes up too many things, plus it feels wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your own keymap:

```
(defvar somename-map (make-sparse-keymap) "Keymap for M-d")
(define-key somename-map (kbd "M-d") 'kill-line)
(define-key somename-map (kbd "M-w") 'kill-word)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-d") somename-map)
```

Comment: keymaps look interesting, however what im trying to acheive is:   when user presses dd (quickly) while the alt key is pressed down, the current line should be deleted.

Comment: I've fixed my example: `M-d` and `M-w` instead `d` and `w`.